# lubuntu - bluetooth no longer works after 18.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, bluetooth, 18.04

I have a problem with the new 18.04 update with Lubuntu.
Before the update the bluetooth manager was working well enough, it would work with both internal and external bluetooth devices but after this upgrade the bluetooth function ceased to work.

I tried uninstalling (purging) and then re-installing all bluetooth packages to no avail.

When I try to open the Bluetooth Manager it says my Bluetooth is disabled, if I click the "Enable" button the aplication crashes and I can't open it again until I reboot.

What could be the cause of this?

`rfkill list` output

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On my laptop it works at first, but quickly disconnects, and then behaves as you describe, as if it never heard of Bluetooth.